# count number of polygons with same geometry in single dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, polygon, geopandas, shapely

I have a single dataframe which contains shapely coordinates for lots of polygons. These polygons overlap and I want to get a count of all overlapping polygons so I can do a heatmap of the distribution. I've developed a solution for this in FME, but I now need to automate it as part of a larger workflow in python. What I've tried so far is:

1. use union overlay to get all possible geometries. I assume that for areas that overlap, there will be multiple identical polygons that link back to the original polygons.

`df_union = gpd.overlay(df_in, df_in, how='union')`

All the examples I found for using union overlay have two input dataframes, but I have just one so I'm not sure if the above is even correct.

If my assumptions are correct, what I can't figure out is now how to count the identical polygons in the single dataframe so that I have results like:

`Count   geometry`

`5  POLYGON ((xxxxxx...
1  POLYGON ((xxxxxx...`

I've tried `df_union.groupby('geometry')` to see if there are identical geometries to count but that produces a result I can't view.

Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A trick around this case is to cast the geometries as strings and then groupy on them.

For example for a data frame of the type

```
df.head()

id  geometry
0   6795584 MULTIPOLYGON (((652670.3 6862958.2, 652675.6 6...
1   6794255 MULTIPOLYGON (((652935.2 6862338.2, 652935 686...
2   6794256 MULTIPOLYGON (((652988.8 6862328.5, 652991.9 6...
3   6794289 MULTIPOLYGON (((653006.6 6862311.6, 653015.2 6...
4   6794290 MULTIPOLYGON (((652998 6862280.3, 652999.8 686..
```

we cast the geometry as a string

```
df.geometry= df.geometry.astype(str)
```

and then we can groupy on it

```
df.groupby('geometry')['id'].count()
```